# OSX Directory not empty cant mv

Tags: macos, mv

Im looking for item that  starts with WaveShell-VST* and want to move t to the mac trash
can (.trash).

So im using that:

```
find  /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'aVST*' -exec mv {} ~/.Trash/ \;
```

when run that command again i get "Directory not empty" message in terminal , how can i force it to move the file to trash either renaming it or deleting what in the trash can?
( I added -f and didn't help).

The 'aVST*' is a directory.

Comment: does it work if you change "`-name 'aVST*'`" to "`-name 'aVST\*'`"??